# Validar formulario en python (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy programando un gui de Python 3 con `tkinter`, se trata de un formulario de usuario y contraseña , tengo dos `entry` una por el usuario y otro para la contraseña y un botón, el botón esta deshabilitado si el usuario deja tanto el nombre y la contraseña vacíos y se debería activar al poner el usuario la contraseña, el problema es que no funciona y permanece desactivado aquí algunas partes del código:

```
LoginButton = Button(marc, text = "Entrar al servidor", font = "Verdana", cursor = "hand2", state = NORMAL)
```

La función es la siguiente:

```
def ValidarLogin():

if Ip.get() == "" or " " and password.get() == "" or " ":
    if (LoginButton['state'] == NORMAL):
        LoginButton['state'] = DISABLED
    else:
        LoginButton['state'] = ACTIVE

return 0
```

Hecho algunos cambios siguen sin funcionar:

```
def ValidarLogin():
mip = Ip.get()
contra = password.get()


if mip != "" and contra != "":
    LoginButton.config(state = NORMAL)
    #if (LoginButton['state'] == NORMAL):
     #   LoginButton['state'] = DISABLED
else:
    LoginButton.config(state = DISABLED)
     #   LoginButton['state'] = ACTIVE

return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con su problema, la solución es agregar una función adicional asociada a la variable de texto que tiene el `Entry`, en este caso `textvariable` el cual hace referencia a la variable del `Entry`. Por lo cual debe definir la variable de cadena o `StringVar` en este caso y posteriormente asignar el método `trace()`.

Un ejemplo sencillo es el siguiente:

```
def EnableButton(*args): # Verificar si hay texto en el cuadro de entrada, si no el botón estará deshabilitado
    try:
        if editWidgetVar.get(): # Variable de texto del cuadro de entrada, verfica si hay texto o no
            btn.config(state='normal')
        else:
            btn.config(state='disabled')
    except:
        print('Excepción no importante, ignorarado...')                

editWidgetVar = tk.StringVar() # Variable de texto del cuadro de entrada
editWidgetVar.trace("w", EnableButton)
editWidget =ttk.Entry(root ,font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), width=34, textvariable=editWidgetVar)
editWidget.place(x=11,y=62, height=21)
editWidget.focus_set()

btn = ttk.Button(root, text='Botón de prueba', takefocus=False, state='disabled') # El estado predeterminado del botón debe estar en 'disabled'
btn.place(x=145,y=96)
```

> El método `trace()` hace referencia a el seguimiento de una variable que es leída, cambia de valor o es borrada. En este caso `trace()` tiene como objetivo verificar mediante la función `EnableButton` en este caso deshabilitar el botón o habilitarlo de nuevo.

Así quedaría en un ejemplo similar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El estado del botón está deshabilitado si no hay texto o valores dentro del `Entry`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El estado del botón cambia por que hay texto en el `Entry` por medio del método `trace()`

El mismo procedimiento se repite si elimina o ingresa el texto en el `Entry`.